# Three.ImageLoader - Object [object Object] has no method 'addEventListener'

Tags: three.js

I'm working on a simple model previewer using three.js, where the user can dynamically upload and change the textures for the model's materials, among other things.

For the life of me I can't get past this error, and I've run across this problem for other loaders in three.js that are supposed to have the addEventListener method. So what am I doing wrong? I'm using r59

```
function loadTex(tex)
{
    var texture = new THREE.Texture();

    var imgloader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );

    imgloader.addEventListener('load', function(event) {
        // Event stuff
    });

    imgloader.load( tex );
}
```

This function gets called after an image successfully uploads to the server. All I'm trying to do is change the texture for a material that already exists.

Comment: Did you maybe recently update Three.js and it was working before? For OBJLoader and other external loaders, you also need to update those files.
For ImageLoader i am not quite sure but you could also just use Three.ImageUtils.loadTexture();

Comment: @GuyGood, thanks for responding. I didn't use ImageLoader before, so can't say if it worked for previous versions. I switched to ImageUtils.loadTexture() instead and it worked fine. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I'm still wondering why the original code didn't work. I may need the .addEventListener method in the future, so I'll probably run into this problem again with various three.js functions. A clear answer would no doubt help other entry-level users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when I upgraded to r59 from r58. It looks like addEventListener method is not available in r59 (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/ImageUtils.js)

You can use loadTexture method and listen to onLoad and onError events

```
function onLoad(event) {
// do something
}

function onError(event) {
// do something
}

texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(url,mapping,onLoad,onError)
```

You can pass {} for mapping or use any of the values defined here

http://threejs.org/docs/59/#Reference/Textures/Texture

Comment: There must be a better way. I had the same issue with the OBJloader and just ended up using the older library.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgloader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
imgloader.load(tex, function(event) {
    // Event stuff
});
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and how that solves the problem *by editing your answer*.